# Azure and Docker Compose : assigning a Resource Group

Tags: azure, docker-compose

I have been following the tutorial on how to run a multi container application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose

I have created a **resource group** for my application that I want to deploy (called "my resource group"). As you can see, its there along with other resource groups.

```
C:\dev\shape-shop-back-end>az group list
[
  {
    "id": "/subscriptions/8cdb50cb-ede8-4eac-80df-55afadf861cd/resourceGroups/cloud-shell-storage-westeurope",
    "location": "westeurope",
    "managedBy": null,
    "name": "cloud-shell-storage-westeurope",
    "properties": {
      "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
    },
    "tags": null,
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups"
  },
  {
    "id": "/subscriptions/8cdb50cb-ede8-4eac-80df-55afadf861cd/resourceGroups/shapeShopResourceGroup",
    "location": "eastus",
    "managedBy": null,
    "name": "shapeShopResourceGroup",
    "properties": {
      "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
    },
    "tags": null,
    "name": "myResourceGroup",
    "properties": {
      "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
    },
    "tags": null,
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups"
  }
]
```

Now when I run **docker compose up**, I get the following error :

```
C:\dev\shape-shop-back-end>docker compose up
[+] Running 0/1
 - Group shape-shop-back-end  Error                                                                                                                                0.6s 
containerinstance.ContainerGroupsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: Code="ResourceGroupNotFound" Message="Resource group '720e631e-ce87-88e3-0cec-ca01ad4f3411' could not be found."
```

This seems unusual to me because in my list I have no resource group called 720e631-blahblahblah.

What confuses me is, how does docker compose know *which* resource group to deploy to? There is nothing in my docker compose yaml file that indicates a resource group.

Is there something like a default resource group? If I can have many resource groups then how I am I supposed to know to which resource group the docker compose is pointing to?

For what its worth here is my docker-compose.yml file.

```
    version: '3.7'
    services:
      app-server:
        image: ollyw123/shapeshop
        ports:
          - "8080:8080" 
        depends_on:
          - db 
        environment: 
          SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/shapeshop?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
          SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
          SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root
          SERVER_PORT: 8080 # must match with ports
        networks:
- backend
    
      db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        restart: always
        environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: shapeshop
          MYSQL_USER: admin
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        networks:
          - backend
    
    volumes:
      db-data2:
    
    networks:
      backend:
```

Answer (score 1):

You selected the resource group when you ran:

```
docker context create aci myacicontext
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose#create-azure-context)

Comment: so is there a one-to-one relationship between an acicontext and a resource group?